# ASP.NET/VB dropdownlist not properly populating gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm rather new to ASP.NET, but I have to create a .aspx form with VB that when selecting a customer from the ddl, it will populate gridview with the customer's orders from an Access database.

So far, my problem is that when I try and select any other customer than the first one, the gridview doesn't repopulate with new information. Rather it stays stuck on the first customer's information.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="Technical_Challenge.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Technical Challenge</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Customers"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CustomerName" DataValueField="CustomerID">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TechChallengeConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TechChallengeConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [CustomerName] FROM [Customers] ORDER BY [CustomerName]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TechChallengeConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TechChallengeConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Orders] WHERE ([CustomerID] = ?)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="CustomerID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="CustomerOrdersLabel" runat="server" Text="Customer Orders">        </asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="OrderID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="OrderID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="OrderID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderPrice" HeaderText="OrderPrice" SortExpression="OrderPrice" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code-behind:

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selecting(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Selecting

    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see either AutoPostBack=True set in your dropdown list or a submit button that would send the data for processing? or you haven't copied that code?

Comment: I guess I didn't realize I needed to change that and I haven't found anything yet specifically for VB. Everything I've found has been in C#, neither of which I'm familiar with. I guess I was assuming that when switching the selection from the ddl it would automatically update. The test queries in Visual Studio I ran seemed like it would work.

So I guess I should see about adding a submit button and how to incorporate an AutoPostBack=True declaration?

Comment: Awesome got it. AutoPostBack="true" is what I wanted to happen. Thanks for your pointer. For anyone wondering the same thing, I just typed in AutoPostBack="true" for the ddl I wanted to have populate the gridview. For Visual Studio, it looks like you can set the AutoPostBack property to true under behavior for the selected dropdownlist. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can either set the `AutoPosBack` of `DropDownList` to True or have a submit button to proceed `PostBack` and re-bind the grid with the data that filtered by your selection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make changes in your code as per below :-

.aspx changes :-

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CustomerName" DataValueField="CustomerID" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The Code-Behind :-

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
     // write your query to select data from database 
    // bind with grid view
End Sub
```